# IIS Rewrite all trafic to SSL

Tags: https, iis-7.5, rewrite

my current configuration is:

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action 
        type="Redirect" 
        url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{R:1}" 
        appendQueryString="true" 
        redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

and links to the http do not work. but when you type in the direct (main) url, the rule described above does work. The links listed on Google do not work; they are without `https`
but the rule should redirect them right? I don't get it.

when I go directly to an image example: `http://www.domain.com/img.jpg` that does not work. https does (when entered manually) what did I do wrong?

Now I have found this website with a sample: http://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action 
        type="Redirect" 
        url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" 
        redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

but that doesn't look so much different. why does my config not redirect google links and direct links to images, but does redirect the main domain. all direct deep links to pages do not work with http. I get a `server not found` exception...

**Edit:** require ssl is not checked in the iis manager

**Edit 2:**

this seems to work:

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action 
        type="Redirect" 
        url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" 
        appendQueryString="true" 
        redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

but that **does not work** for:
http://www.domain.com/app_themes/themeName/img.jpg

and for 
http://www.domain.com/urlrewritten
(rewritten with maproutes in global.asax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action 
        type="Redirect" 
        url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" 
        appendQueryString="true" 
        redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

works, also with url rewriting of mapping routes etc. tested in internet explorer, firefox and chrome :)